# Android shape border with gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I want to create a border for a linearLayout. So I decide to create a shape. I want the border to have a gradient. The following is not doing it. It fills the rectangle and then creates a stroke. I don't want a filled rectangle, just the stroke. And I want to apply the gradient to the stroke.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="360"
        android:centerColor="#e95a22"
        android:endColor="#ff00b5"
        android:gradientRadius="360"
        android:startColor="#006386"
        android:type="sweep" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff207d94" />

</shape>
```

Comment: see https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830790/add-gradient-in-edit-text-border-in-android/39831707, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496583/android-create-gradient-border/37498686.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#e95a22"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#006386"
                android:type="sweep" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ff207d94" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the solid color of the second item?

Comment: it is the color of the button it self

Comment: Jesus Dimrix you mean the layout

Comment: @vipul , how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322955/android-shape-border-with-gradient-and-middle-transparent?

Comment: how to do it for black and white color?

Comment: There's no way of adding `ripple` to `layer-list` :(

Comment: thanx it helped me :)

Answer (score 44):

since the accepted answer didn't work exactly as i wanted it to work for me, i'll post my solution too, maybe it helps someone else :)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
<!-- create gradient you want to use with the angle you want to use -->
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:endColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:startColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    </shape>
</item>
<!-- create the stroke for top, left, bottom and right with the dp you want -->
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <!-- fill the inside in the color you want (could also be a gradient again if you want to, just change solid to gradient and enter angle, start, maybe center, and end color) -->
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: After a lot of searches, I got the perfect solution. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Not perfect, since my EditTexts' fill is supposed to be transparent.

Comment: Starwave in the solid rectngle you should be able to use @android:color/transparent this should do the trick. or you just use alpha by setting the collor to e.g. #00FFFFFF

Comment: I want to add radius on the corners, how can I define the corner radius?

Comment: @HAXM inside the <shape tag add e.g. <corners android:radius="12dp" /> for a 12 dp corner radius.
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
If you need different corner radius for each corner you can use bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius, topLeftRadius and topRightRadius instead of radius.

Answer (score 6):

This will create a layout with top border of 2dp.
just set it as a background to your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#4fc949"
                android:centerColor="#0c87c5"
                android:endColor="#b4ec51"
                android:angle="180" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/background_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

This extra source should fix your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#e95a22"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#006386"
                android:type="sweep" />
            <size android:height="170dp"
                android:width="170dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="140dp"
                android:height="140dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be the appropriate solution to what you wanna do. It includes gradient in stroke as well as a gradient in fill colour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape >
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#2196F3"
                    android:endColor="#673AB7"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="0dp"
                    android:color="@color/transparentColor" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="8dp" />
                <padding
                    android:left="2dp"
                    android:right="2dp"
                    android:top="2dp"
                    android:bottom="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="0dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#FBB100"
                    android:endColor="#FF9900"
                    android:angle="270"/>

                <corners
                    android:radius="8dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks! What for is an empty second `<item>`? What for is the first `<stroke>` with transparent color?

Answer (score 0):

I think the gradient borders with rounded corners are not possible with just XML.
You have to build a custom view to achieve this.

Here is an example that I have build with which you can set gradient borders and custom fill colors.

[image]

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.LinearGradient
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.graphics.Shader
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import com.example.helper.ui.utils.dpToPx

class GradientViewWithBorders : View {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private var porterDuffXfermode_SRC_OVER = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
    private var viewWidth = 0
    private var viewHeight = 0

    var startColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
    var endColor = Color.parseColor("#50FFFFFF")

    var startFillColor = Color.parseColor("#50FFFFFF")

    var endFillColor = Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")

    var lineStrokeWidth = 1f

    val strokeGradient: LinearGradient by lazy {
        LinearGradient(
            0f,
            0f,
            this.viewWidth.toFloat(),
            this.viewHeight.toFloat(),
            startColor,
            endColor,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    }


    val fillGradient: LinearGradient by lazy {
        LinearGradient(
            0f,
            0f,
            this.viewWidth.toFloat(),
            this.viewHeight.toFloat(),
            startFillColor,
            endFillColor,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    }

    var rect = RectF()
    val corners = floatArrayOf(
        0f, 0f,  // Top, left in px
        0f, 0f,  // Top, right in px
        context.dpToPx(12f), context.dpToPx(12f),  // Bottom, right in px
        context.dpToPx(12f), context.dpToPx(12f) // Bottom,left in px
    )

    val outlinePath = Path()
    val innerPath = Path()


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attributeSet)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attributeSet,
        defStyleAttr
    )


    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        this.viewWidth = w
        this.viewHeight = h

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        paint.apply {
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            maskFilter = null
            shader = strokeGradient
            xfermode = porterDuffXfermode_SRC_OVER
            strokeWidth = context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth)
        }

        rect.set(
            context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) + paddingLeft,
            context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) + paddingTop,
            viewWidth.toFloat() - context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) - paddingRight,
            viewHeight.toFloat() - context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) - paddingBottom
        )


        outlinePath.addRoundRect(rect, corners, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(outlinePath, paint)





        paint.apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            maskFilter = null
            shader = fillGradient
            xfermode = porterDuffXfermode_SRC_OVER
            strokeWidth = 0f
        }


        rect.set(
            context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) + paddingLeft + context.dpToPx(0.5f),
            context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) + paddingTop + context.dpToPx(0.5f),
            viewWidth.toFloat() - context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) - paddingRight - context.dpToPx(
                0.5f
            ),
            viewHeight.toFloat() - context.dpToPx(lineStrokeWidth) - paddingBottom - context.dpToPx(
                0.5f
            )
        )


        innerPath.addRoundRect(rect, corners, Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.drawPath(innerPath, paint)

    }
}
```