# Android, Create gradient border?

Tags: android, xml, gradient

I know it's frustrating after all similar posts at stackoverflow. I've surfed a lot of posts but i really couldn't solve my problem. So please help! I want to set a gradient border via xml like the image:

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: use a  nine patch image

Comment: How to create the image to feed nine patch maker?

Comment: marker? What marker?

Comment: nine patch maker, dude:) I searched and kind of i need a base image to create nine patch!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Customized as per your design, create a drawable file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="8px">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#08000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="3px"
                        android:left="3px"
                        android:right="3px"
                        android:top="3px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#09000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#10000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#11000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#12000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#13000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#14000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#15000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#16000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#17000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And set as background of your layout

Comment: And as a matter of criticism, in such an irregular atmosphere here at stackoverflow which some guys simply come and just vote down for the reason they just know themselves, which not only doesn't help, but also sucks! You simply answered my question and solved my problem. The community needs people like you. I humbly thank you.@milan-pansuriya

Comment: By the way, i needed some rounded corners which was done just by adding <corners android:radius="4dp" /> to each shape . Thanks again.

Comment: An issue is sometimes the shadow effect gets solid, like just the far outer layer and most inner layer are working and layers between the two are not taking place! Each time this happens, it gets fixed after two runs of my app! and i don't know why?