# How to get rid of shadow that appears on my button? Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shapedrawable, gradientdrawable

I have created a button with a Gradient Drawable.

[image]

If you look at this button, it has those Extra Grey lines as pointed out by my red arrows. Those don't appear if I create a shape using XML but when i use

Gradient Drawable code seen below  it shows these lines. How do I get rid of them??

```
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")); 
    gd.setCornerRadius(20);
    gd.setStroke(30, Color.parseColor("#0077CC"));
    Button.setBackground(gd);
```

These become more apparent if i increase the setCorner Radius

Comment: set its elevation to 0dp

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i tried setting ```elevation=0dp``` for the button in the XML but still showing those shadows

Comment: @Farya hi sir, I just tried ```SetCorner Radius = 30``` but shadow still shows

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496583/android-create-gradient-border/37498686#37498686 this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style to your button.

`style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`