# Add gradient in edit text border in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, border, gradient

I want to add gradient only to the border of my editText , I can add gradient but it takes the entire background . How can I apply gradient only to the border , and the rest should be transparent?

[image]

Comment: Figured it out yet?

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This one does the trick :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#0256FC"
                android:centerColor="#0256FC"
                android:startColor="#FE00B1" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <size
                android:width="162dp"
                android:height="44dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but not transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the **edittext** in a layout
- Set gradient background color for that layout
- Set margin 1dp for **edittext**.
- Set white background for **edittext**

i think now it's displays like your expectation, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Create your **button_border.xml** and keep it within drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/white" >
</stroke>

<!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"   >
</corners>

</shape>
```

Now set your editText background as follows :

```
android:background="@drawable/button_border"
```

Comment: This is not providing gradient background.