# How to apply radialGradient on stroke of arc in a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-paint

I'm drawing arc with canvas.drawArc(...) and use below code to add gradient to paint object but the gradient just applied on the body of arc and not the stroke. how to draw a gradient stroke?

```
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2,mRadius/2,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        canvas.drawArc(new RectF(getWidth()/2-mRadius, getHeight()/2-mRadius, getWidth()/2+mRadius, getHeight()/2+mRadius),270f,mProgressDegree,true,paint);
```

Comment: I think Android does not support Gradient Shader for Stroke type style.
Check a similar question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870853/android-shape-border-with-gradient

Comment: In your code you draw stroke only, not a "body". To draw "body" use Style.FILL